# what will be the output of the nand gate in boolean form?the answer given in question is AB+BC+CA

Tags: decoder

[image][image]

the image shown below is a 3:8 decoder and s1,s2,s3 are the inputs to the decoder circuitry

Comment: Looks like a home work. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have posted the solution which i tried.Can u please tell me where am i going wrong in solving this question?

Comment: The bubble at the output of decoder says that the output is inverted. So \$D_7\$ will be `'0'` if `ABC = '111'` and so on...

Comment: One more thing. `AB+BC+CA` is not the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The bubbles on the output terminals of the decoder say that the output is inverted.

So output of NAND gate will be:

$$Y = (\overline{\overline{CBA})(\overline{CB\overline{A}})(\overline{C\overline{B}A})(\overline{C\overline{B}\ \overline{A}}})$$

By DeMorgan,s theorem,
$$Y = CBA + CB\overline{A} + C\overline{B}A + C\overline{B}\ \overline{A} = C$$

It is obvious from the figure that output will be high if and only if \$C='1'\$. So the answer given in the question is wrong.

Comment: thanks, i also got the same answer when you told about my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The problem presented is meant to be solved by inspection as opposed to working out long combinatorial equations. (Although there is nothing wrong with the equation solution, it just takes more time).

There is also a serious flaw in the diagram presented in the problem. The notation shown as O<sub>1</sub> is meant to be O<sub>7</sub>.

You are meant to think of the NAND gate as its DeMorgan equivalent. Then, given that you know how a low true output 3->8 decoder works, the answer should indeed pop out by inspection.

[image]

Comment: Sir, initially i did the problem in wrong way but i have read in my book 2 level NAND gate circuit is equivalent to the two level AND-OR circuit and after oring the O4,O5,O6,O7 i get the answer as C.